# How to set local notifications in iphone app?

Tags: objective-c

In my project I need to set the notifications on list and please let me know how to compare the list names. And if list name is different then it will save otherwise not.

Here is my code-

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender{
    if ([listName.text isEqualToString:@"" ]) {
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Please enter List Name." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [error show];

    } else if (self.newlist ) {
        if (listName.text.length > 0  ) {


            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
            NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
            NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
            if (notification.on ) {
                NSString *dateStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",dateString, time.text ];

                [self saveList:dateStr:dateString];
                [self saveListImages];
                [self getlistdata];
            }else {
                [self saveList:@"2000-01-01 00:00":dateString];
            }
        }else{
            [listName becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }else{
        NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
        NSString *dateStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",dateString, time.text ];
        if ([self updateList:dateStr:dateString]) {
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Update List" message:@"List is successfully updated!" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [message show];
        }else{
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Update List" message:@"There is some issue please try after some time!" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [message show];

        }
        [self getlistdata];
        ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
        //viewController.delegate = self;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                        initWithRootViewController:viewController];
        [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];

        //        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }


}
-(void) saveList: (NSString *)timeNotfi : (NSString *) createdate{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dexternotedb.sqlite"];
    NSString *notifcationBool = (notification.on)? @"1":@"0";
    //NSString *alarmBool = (alarm.on)? @"1":@"0";
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO list (notification, list_name, notification_repeat, notification_time, create_date) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\",\"%ld\", \"%@\")", notifcationBool,[listName text] ,(long)selectedRepeat,timeNotfi,createdate];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Dexter's Note" message:@"New list is successfully added!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [message show];
            ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
            //viewController.delegate = self;
            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                            initWithRootViewController:viewController];
            [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];

        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Dexter's Note" message:@"failed!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [message show];
            ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
            //viewController.delegate = self;
            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                            initWithRootViewController:viewController];
            [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);

        //[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }


}
-(void)getlistdata{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dexternotedb.sqlite"];
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE notification = 1";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSString *notificationtime = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
                int notificationrepeat = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
                NSDate *pickerDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:notificationtime];
                [self setLocalNotification:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] : pickerDate : notificationrepeat : sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1)];
                [self saveListImages];

            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } else {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<[notificationArray count]; i++) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:[notificationArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
-(void)saveListImages {
    if(sqlite3_open([[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:image] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM image where id=%i"];
        //NSLog(@";query = \n%@";, query);
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                if (sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0) != NULL) {
                    //NSLog(@";read a non NULL image");
                    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0)];
                    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@";read a NULL image");
                }
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
-(void)setLocalNotification:(NSString *) listname : (NSDate *)date : (int) ReapeatNotification : (int) listId{

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = date;
    localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
    localNotif.alertBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Its time for %@", listname];
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    localNotif.soundName =@"low_power.wav";
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [APP_DELEGATE increaseCounter];
    NSString *listIdStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",listId];
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:listIdStr forKey:@"list_id"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
    switch (ReapeatNotification) {
        case 1:
            //            localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            localNotif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
            break;
        case 2:
            localNotif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    [notificationArray addObject:localNotif];
    //    NSLog(@"size%d",[notificationArray count]);
    sqlite3_close(database);


}
-(BOOL) updateList: (NSString *)timeNotfi : (NSString *) createdate{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dexternotedb.sqlite"];
    NSString *notifcationBool = (notification.on)? @"1":@"0";
    //NSString *alarmBool = (alarm.on)? @"1":@"0";
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NewListViewController *temp = APP_DELEGATE.listViewController;
        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE list SET list_name = '%@', notification = %@,  notification_repeat = %d, notification_time = '%@', create_date = '%@' WHERE list_id = %d", [listName text], notifcationBool, selectedRepeat, timeNotfi, createdate, [temp.listSettingID integerValue]];
        NSLog(@"%@",updateSQL);
        const char *insert_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];


        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return true;
        }else{
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return false;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return false;
}
```